# Jquery reformat time second

Tags: jquery

I have retrieve a data and it format like this `00:00:00.0381136` but I only need `0381136` in jquery how to format it ? Any idea ? thanks

Comment: What are the other possible data values? Otherwise, you can use `split` as suggested by @CodingCracker.

`var testDate ="00:00:00.0381136" ; console.log(teststr.split("\.")[1]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve using jquery `split()` function. Check [Manual](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).

```
var time = "00:00:00.0381136";
alert(time.split(".")[1]);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r9x6pw5x/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use this [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ybdd7cw9/)

```
var time = '00:00:00.0381136';
var result = time.split('.');
console.log(result[1]);
```